# How to make Android Jetifier works with databinding?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding, androidx, android-jetifier

My Android project has 2 Android library modules: `app` and `boo`.
`app` module has already migrated to AndroidX, `boo` is still using support library.

In `boo` module, I want to add a new library that depends on both support library and uses data binding.

I have enable Android Jetifier in my `gradle.properties`.
I am using Android Gradle build tool v.3.3.2 and Gradle v.5.3.1.

Here is my gradle.properies

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
kotlin.code.style=official
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

My `app`'s build.gradle that use AndroidX.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
nit:4.12'
    implementation project(':boo')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
}
```

My `boo`'s build.gradle. The module depends on a library that uses both databinding and support library.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation <library with support library and data binding>
```

```
databinding/LayoutWallBinding.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public final android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout orderingLayout;
                                           ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: package android.support.constraint

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':editor:kaptDebugKotlin'.
```

I expect Android Jetifier to convert all support libraries including to AndroidX, but it seems like it cannot convert the `ConstraintLayout` generated from data binding to AndroidX.

Answer (score 1):

No,it's not working like that 
   If you want to use AndroidX then it's mandatory that you use all libraries of AndroidX not Support libs
   so Instead of  this:

```
implementation'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Use this:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: The same goes for MultiDex and RecyclerView in this case. All your dependencies must point to AndroidX instead of support library. Jetifier only converts third-party library dependencies. Where you can you must fix the dependencies yourself (in your projects). You can go to Main Menu > Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score -1):

Convert your library to androidX using standalone [jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier#install_jetifier) and see if it helps.

```
./jetifier-standalone -i libraryToProcess.aar -o result.aar
```

Comment: How is this applicable to this case? I don't see any aar in the question. This is too low level.

Comment: I think this will only convert all code in the library itself to AndroidX but not its dependencies.